# Count the word frequency of every phrase per row in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(phrase = c("text 1","this text 2", "text 3"))
```

and I would like to create a column which will contain the number of phrases with exist in every row in the dataframe. Example from the previous respectively 2,3,2

What I tried is this

```
library(data.table)

dfN<- setDT(DF)[, c('phrase') :=tstrsplit(phrase, '(?<=[^0-9])', perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]
```

but I receive this error

> Error in [.data.table(setDT(DF), , :=(c("phrase"),
>   tstrsplit(phrase,  : 
>         Internal logical error. Up front checks (before starting to modify DT) didn't catch type of RHS ('list') assigning to factor
>   column 'phrase'. Please report to datatable-help.
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In [.data.table(setDT(DF), , :=(c("phrase"), tstrsplit(phrase,  :
>         Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 3 items of column 'phrase' (8 unused)

Comment: You have several columns by splitting and u r assigning to a single column i.e. phrase'

Comment: @akrun thank you. What can I do for this?

Comment: It is not clear about the output.  If you want the number of words, then `setDT(DF)[, newcol := str_count(phrase, "\\w+")]`

Comment: @akrun thank you this is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
setDT(DF)[, newcol := str_count(phrase, "\\w+")]
```